# On the Finite Sum of Reciprocal Fibonacci Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

I want to check if $$\left \lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right) ^{-1} \right\rfloor =F_{2n-1}~~(n\ge 3)\qquad(*)$$  where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is a floor function.

Fibonacci sequence is defined by $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$, $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}~(n\ge 2)$. Then we can get $$F_n=\dfrac{\alpha ^n-\beta ^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$
where $\alpha=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

The following are some of my attempts:

> For  some example:
>
> $n=3$, the left hand is $5$, the right hand is $5.$
>
> $n=4$, the left hand is $13$, the right hand is $13.$
>
> $$\vdots$$
>
> $n=15$, the left hand is $514229$, the right hand is $514229.$
>
> It is all true. But as $n$ increases, the order of magnitude grows
> very rapidly.
>
> I ask one of my good friends to ues a Python program to check $(*).$
> He says it is true for $n\le 35$. When $n=36$, the Python says it is not ture, But when $n= 37$, it is true again.
>
> Thus I change one way and  I ask my fiend to use a Python program to
> check $$\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right) ^{-1}
>  =F_{2n-1}~~(n\ge 3)\qquad(**).$$
>
> Then the program shows it is true at least for $31\le n\le 51.$
>
> But as you see, the left hand  of $(**)$ is a decimal and the right hand  of $(**)$ is an integer.

So I donot know if it is because the order of magnitude on the left hand of $(*)$ is growing very fast, $(*)$ becomes not true due to some computer shortcomings.

Finally I wonder if $(*)$ is true or false? Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I have also posted it on [On the Finite Sum of Reciprocal Fibonacci Sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452159/on-the-finite-sum-of-reciprocal-fibonacci-sequences).

---

Update: This identity comes from similiar identities.

> $(1):$ In Hideyuki Ohtsuka and Shigeru Nakamura's paper "ON THE SUM OF
> RECIPROCAL FIBONACCI NUMBERS", they found  $$\lfloor \left(
>  \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_k}} \right) ^{-1} \rfloor
>  =\begin{cases}  F_{n-2},    n\,\,\mathrm{is}\,\,\mathrm{even}\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,n\geqslant 2.\\
>   F_{n-2}-1,
>  n\,\,\mathrm{is}\,\,\mathrm{odd}\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,n\geqslant 1.\\
>  \end{cases}.$$
>
> $(2):$ In a master's thesis  "On the sum of reciprocal fibonacci
> numbers" written by Guojie Zhang, he found
>
> $$\lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{3k}}} \right) ^{-1}
>  \rfloor =\begin{cases}  F_{3n-1}+F_{3n-4},   
>  n\,\,\mathrm{is}\,\,\mathrm{even}\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,n\geqslant 2.\\
>   F_{3n-1}+F_{3n-4}-1,
>  n\,\,\mathrm{is}\,\,\mathrm{odd}\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,n\geqslant 3.\\
>  \end{cases}$$
>
> $$\lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{4k}}} \right) ^{-1}
>  \rfloor =F_{4n-1}+F_{4n-3}-1.$$
>
> $(3):$ In a paper "The finite sum of reciprocal of the Fibonacci
> numbers" written by Wu, ZG Wang, they found $$\lfloor \left(
>  \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_k}} \right) ^{-1} \rfloor =F_{n-2}.$$
>
> There are many other similar results and so on.

So I guess why there is no $2k$ identity and  I use computer to get $(*)$, but I donnot know how to prove it for any integer $n\ge 3$.

Comment: I've programmed this in Matlab and compared results out to $n=100$. If find that there are discrepancies at $n\ge36$ but not for all $n$. However, the *percentage* difference is of the the order of $10^{-14}$ and I would assume that these arise due to floating point issues with the processor. Can you tell us where you found this identity?

Comment: I've taken this up to $n=700$ with the same result. For larger $n$, however, the results deteriorate quickly because the result is pushing the floating point limit.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452159/on-the-finite-sum-of-reciprocal-fibonacci-sequences without informing either site. That's a violation of policy on both sites.

Comment: @Cye Waldman I have updated some information. I might guess the identity$(*).$

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson  Sorry, I didn't know about this before. I've posted links on both sides.

Comment: @fusheng For many forums, it's (at best) impolite to simultaneously post elsewhere because it can lead to readers wasting their time not know that the answer may have already been found elsewhere. For example, three different answers with at least two different proofs are now on the MO question.

Comment: On the issue of $n\le3$, have you considered ($\lfloor xxx \rceil$), i.e., *round* instead of the *floor*? I find that that works for all $n$, as well. And speaking of $n\ge3$, I find that the equality is also valid for the Lucas numbers.

Comment: @ Teepeemm  I'm sorry, I have known that. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sketch of how such a result might accrue. We are asked if

$$\left \lfloor\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right) ^{-1}\right\rfloor
 =F_{2n-1}~~(n\ge 3)$$

We shall assume that $n$ is a large number, so that we may take advantage of certain simplifications. Consider first, that

$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}\approx\frac{\varphi^n}{\varphi-\psi}\quad \text{ for large }n$$

where $\varphi,\psi=(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$ . Then

$$\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right)=(\varphi-\psi)\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{\varphi^{2k}}} \right)=\frac{\varphi-\psi}{\varphi^{2n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{\frac{1}{\varphi^{2k}}} \right)$$

Now, let $x=1/\varphi^2$, so that the summation becomes

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{\frac{1}{\varphi^{2k}}}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...x^{n-1}\approx\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{\varphi^2}{\varphi^2-1}=\varphi$$

again, for sufficiently large $n$. Then we can say

$$\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right)=\frac{(\varphi-\psi)}{\varphi^{2n}}\varphi\approx\frac{1}{F_{2n-1}}$$

and finally

$$\left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right) ^{-1} =F_{2n-1}\quad(n>>3)$$