# On the infinite Sum of Reciprocal Fibonacci Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

The question comes from [On the Finite Sum of Reciprocal Fibonacci Sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747937/on-the-finite-sum-of-reciprocal-fibonacci-sequences) and [On the finite sum of reciprocal Fibonacci sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452159/on-the-finite-sum-of-reciprocal-fibonacci-sequences).

Althouth I cannot prove the identity $$\left\lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{\frac{1}{F_{2k}}} \right) ^{-1} \right\rfloor =F_{2n-1}~~~~(n\ge 3)(*),$$ I seem to prove this identity

$$\lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}} \right) ^{-1} \rfloor =F_{2n}.$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is th floor function.

Here's my attempts.

For any integer $n$, $F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F^2_{n}=(-1)^n$

This is equivalent to proving that
$$\dfrac{1}{F_{2n}+1}<\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}}<\dfrac{1}{F_{2n}}.$$

Firstly, we prove $$\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}+1}<\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+2}+1}.$$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}+1}-\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}-\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+2}+1}
&=\dfrac{F_{2k+1}^{2}-\left( F_{2k}+1 \right) \left( F_{2k+2}+1 \right)}{\left( F_{2k}+1 \right) F_{2k+1}\left( F_{2k+2}+1 \right)}\\
&=\dfrac{-F_{2k}-F_{2k+2}}{\left( F_{2k}+1 \right) F_{2k+1}\left( F_{2k+2}+1 \right)}\\&<0.
\end{align*}

Secondly, we proof $$\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}}>\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+2}}.$$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}}-\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}-\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+2}}
&=\dfrac{F_{2k+1}F_{2k+1}-F_{2k}F_{2k+2}}{F_{2k}F_{2k+1}F_{2k+2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{F_{2k}F_{2k+1}F_{2k+2}}\\&>0.
\end{align*}

$(1)$: $$\dfrac{1}{F_{2n}}>\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+2}}>\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+2}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+4}}>\cdots>\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}}.$$

$(2):$
$$\dfrac{1}{F_{2n}+1}<\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+2}+1}<\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+3}}+\dfrac{1}{F_{2n+5}+1}<\cdots<\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}}.$$

So I can get $$\lfloor \left( \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\dfrac{1}{F_{2k+1}}} \right) ^{-1} \rfloor =F_{2n}.$$

Do I try it right? Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!